# Quelle est la différence entre « en » et « dans » ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

J'ai écrit :

> Si les thèses sont écrites **en** la même langue, ...

Parce qu'on dit : **Il explique en français**, je pensais que il n'y avait pas de problèmes à écrire ça comme ça.

Mais mon professeur de français a corrigé cette phrase en :

> Si les thèses sont écrites **dans** la même langue, ...

Quand est-ce qu'on écrit **dans** ?

Et quelle est la différence entre **en** et **dans** ?

Answer (score 7):

Ici, dans le contexte des langues, la différence tient à la présence ou non d'un article (d'un déterminant) dans ce qui suit la préposition :

> Il s'exprime **en** français, **en** anglais, **en** espagnol, etc.
>
> Il s'exprime **dans une** langue étrangère, **dans la** langue de Shakespeare.

On retrouve cette différence avec ces exemples :

> Je suis en vacances **dans les** Alpes. ( <s>en Alpes</s> )
>
> Je suis en vacances **en** Corse. ( <s>dans la Corse</s> )

*En le/la/les* est une combinaison désuète qui ne subsiste que dans des expressions figées comme :

> Le mariage sera célébré **en l**'église de Notre-Dame de Paris.

---

Si *en* et *dans* sont utilisés dans un contexte temporel ou spatial, ce n'est pas la présence ou non d'un déterminant qui importe mais le sens :

> Il part **dans** une heure : une heure plus tard que maintenant
>
> Comment parler français **en** une heure : il suffit d'une heure pour apprendre à parler français
>
> Il part **dans** l'heure : il part entre maintenant et dans une heure
>
> **Dans** deux kilomètres : deux kilomètres plus loin
>
> **En** deux kilomètres : durant deux kilomètres

Answer (score 1):

Il est question de toute une gamme d'usages et une réponse suffisamment détaillée ne peut être que très longue, voir [« en »](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?20;s=1103025195;r=1;nat=;sol=9;) et [« dans »](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?11;s=952620075;r=1;nat=;sol=0;). La présente réponse n'abordera que quelques questions et pas toutes les plus importantes.

On peut néanmoins donner tout d'abord une caractérisation générale.

Premièrement, il existe une tendance à utiliser « dans » pour des relation de contenance basique (de l'eau dans le vase, du sucre dans l'eau, du carbone dans le sucre) et « en » lorsque la relation de contenance n'est pas si explicite ou pas l'idée dominante (en été (dans ce temps de l'année correspondant à l'été), de l'eau en bouteilles de 2l) ; cependant il ne s'agit que d'une tendance.

- de l'eau dans des [récipients](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eau+dans+des+r%C3%A9cipients%2Ceau+en+r%C3%A9cipients&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceau%20dans%20des%20r%C3%A9cipients%3B%2Cc0) ( « de l'eau en récipients » ne se trouve pas ou doit être très rare)

Secondement, « en » s'utilise

- pour des relations qui se situent strictement au niveau de la manière (bien qu'occasionnellement elles soient voisines du moyen), de la matière
- pour la formation de locutions.

TLFi

**1. Loc. adv. et prépositives**
**a) En + adv.**
Loc. de lieu En deçà (de), en dessous (de), en dedans (de), en dehors (de), en travers (de)
 
Loc. de manière. En trop, en plus (de).
Loc. adv. de liaison. En outre. Le médecin légiste, qui dirigeait en outre un service à l'hôpital municipal
**b) En + subst.**
 Loc. de lieu. En face, en bas, en haut. la maison d'en face ; Tout vient d'en-haut! 
 Loc. de manière. En foule, en cachette. Il monte en tapinois l'escalier _ Pierres en vrac.
 Loc. adv. de liaison. En fait, en effet, en conséquence, en réalité, en revanche. En quelque sorte. Ce grotesque quelqu'un en l'occurrence le personnage ci-dessus décrit? 
c) **En + adj.**
 Loc. de lieu. En long, en large. On me l'a expliqué en long et en large à la maison.
 Loc. de manière. En gros, en général, en douce, en clair, en vain, en bref. On devrait tâcher de le descendre en douce. Agir en secret.
 Loc. adv. de liaison. En particulier, en définitive.
**2. Loc. conj.** En ce que, en attendant que, en cas que, en sorte que.
**3. Loc. verbales.** Consister en, croire en, espérer en, traiter en.
**4. Mots composés.** En-tête, en-cas, boute-en-train, monte-en-l'air, croc-en-jambe.

- **manière** en chantant, en vert, en pointillé, …
- **matière** en fer, en buis, en plastique, …

Troisièmement, on peut dire qu'avec « dans » on utilise les articles alors qu'avec  « en » on les utilise moins.

Quatrièmement, « en » est utilisé pour les contenances ou états « fonctionnels » ou situations qui impliquent des routines spéciales (en caisse, en boite, en pot, en travail, en classe, en terminale, en colère, en l'état (*aussi, synonyme*, dans l'état que c'est), en état … )

Par exemple on dit « en ville », « en montagne », mais « à la campagne » et « aux champs » ou « dans la campagne » et « dans les champs ».

Voici un exemple de ce qui est suggéré.

- Il avait **en tête/dans la tête** toute la section du catalogue qui traite des ustensiles de camping.
  *Il s'agit ici de la préservation systématique d'information dans la mémoire.*
- Le surveillant avait **dans la tête/dans l'idée/en tête** de punir cet élève depuis longtemps déjà.
  *Il n'est plus question de préservation mais simplement de se rappeler, d'avoir présent à l'esprit (« Le siège abstrait ou concret d'une sensation, d'une pensée » nous dit le TLFi).*

Cet autre exemple ne permet plus aucune caractérisation de différence, il n'est plus question que d'usage ;

- (TLFi) **Dans le fond, dans l'ensemble** [[sens]] Si on se place au point de vue du fond, de l'ensemble. Synon. **en gros, en général**

-------------------------------------------------- **Certains cas d'usage**---------------------------------------------------

1. **Villes** : dans Düsseldorf, dans Turin, dans Limoges, … (*vieux ou provençal*) : en Arles, en Avignon, …
2. **Noms de pays lorsque ils sont accompagnés d'une épithète ou d'un complément** : dans la France de ce temps-là, dans l'Allemagne dévastée, dans la Russie impériale,…
3. **Noms de pays non modifiés** : en France, en Autriche, en Finlande, …
4. **Noms de régions** : parfois « en », parfois « dans » _ en Provence, en Auvergne, en Bretagne, en lorraine, en Guyenne, en Picardie, … dans le Massif Central, dans le Roussillon, dans les Causses, dans les Cévennes, …
5. **Périodes**

   - **années** (*« en » pour une année donnée*) : en 1995, en l'an 10, en l'année (*souvent lorsque suivi du numéro de l'année), *mais aussi* dans l'année (*souvent lorsque suivi d'un complément*) ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dans+l%27ann%C3%A9e+*%2Cen+l%27ann%C3%A9e+*&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cdans%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdans%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%20qui%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdans%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdans%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%20du%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdans%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%20m%C3%AAme%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdans%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%20o%C3%B9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdans%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%20suivante%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdans%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdans%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%20pr%C3%A9c%C3%A9dente%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdans%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%20et%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdans%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%201%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cen%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ben%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%201%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ben%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%20mil%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ben%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%201583%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ben%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%20mille%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ben%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ben%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%201610%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ben%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%201668%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ben%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%201666%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ben%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%201660%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ben%20l%27%20ann%C3%A9e%201639%3B%2Cc0))
     (*« dans » pour une période longue d'un an ou plus*) « Dans deux ans/deux années » => le point dans le temps qui se trouve après qu'une période de deux ans est passée
   - **mois** : en mai, en septembre, … *cependant* dans le mois de mai (*ou* au mois de mai)
   - **semaine** : *les deux sont utilisés avec des sens différents.*  en semaine  =>   pendant les jours normalement consacrés au travail  (TLFi);  dans la semaine => dans les limites du temps de la semaine en train de passer ;  en une semaine => dans le temps qui correspond à celui d'une semaine entière ; dans une semaine => après que le temps qui correspond à celui d'une semaine entière se sera écoulé.
   - **instant**  Dans un instant => un point dans le temps situé immédiatement après la durée de temps que prend un instant ;  en un instant => la durée de temps que prend un instant.
   - **siècles** : *on dit*  « au XXe siècle » ou « dans le siècle » ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=au+si%C3%A8cle+*%2Cdans+le+si%C3%A8cle+*&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cau%20si%C3%A8cle%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bau%20si%C3%A8cle%20dernier%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bau%20si%C3%A8cle%20suivant%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bau%20si%C3%A8cle%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bau%20si%C3%A8cle%20des%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bau%20si%C3%A8cle%20pr%C3%A9c%C3%A9dent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bau%20si%C3%A8cle%20pass%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bau%20si%C3%A8cle%20d%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bau%20si%C3%A8cle%20o%C3%B9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bau%20si%C3%A8cle%20qui%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bau%20si%C3%A8cle%20et%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cdans%20le%20si%C3%A8cle%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdans%20le%20si%C3%A8cle%20dernier%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdans%20le%20si%C3%A8cle%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdans%20le%20si%C3%A8cle%20suivant%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdans%20le%20si%C3%A8cle%20o%C3%B9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdans%20le%20si%C3%A8cle%20pass%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdans%20le%20si%C3%A8cle%20pr%C3%A9c%C3%A9dent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdans%20le%20si%C3%A8cle%20des%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdans%20le%20si%C3%A8cle%20qui%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdans%20le%20si%C3%A8cle%20pr%C3%A9sent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdans%20le%20si%C3%A8cle%20d%27%3B%2Cc0))
     On ne touve pas « en le siècle » mais on trouve en abondance « en **un** siècle » suivi d'un complémént ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=en+le+si%C3%A8cle+*%2Cen+un+si%C3%A8cle+*&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cen%20un%20si%C3%A8cle%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ben%20un%20si%C3%A8cle%20o%C3%B9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ben%20un%20si%C3%A8cle%20et%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ben%20un%20si%C3%A8cle%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ben%20un%20si%C3%A8cle%20qui%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ben%20un%20si%C3%A8cle%20d%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ben%20un%20si%C3%A8cle%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ben%20un%20si%C3%A8cle%20la%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ben%20un%20si%C3%A8cle%20dans%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ben%20un%20si%C3%A8cle%20ou%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ben%20un%20si%C3%A8cle%20que%3B%2Cc0))

5.**Auteurs et leurs œuvres** (TLFi) [Devant des noms propres d'écrivains, d'artistes, lorsqu'on envisage la personne même et non son œuvre[, laquelle est] exprimée par « dans »]

- (TLFi) Ce n'est nullement la drôlerie qui me ravit en Molière, mais bien la langue, admirable entre toutes.
- Cela peut se lire dans Gides.

6.**États d'esprit**

- **en** ou **dans** en liesse/dans la liesse, en joie/dans la joie, en folie/dans la folie, en colère/dans la colère, …
  Pour certains états d'esprit, « en » n'est pas utilisé et seulement « dans » l'est ; dans le bonheur, dans le malheur, dans la surprise, dans la déception …
- presque seulement **dans** *lorsque ces états d'esprit sont attribués au moyen d'un [possessif](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dans+sa+liesse%2Cdans+sa+folie%2Cdans+sa+joie%2Cen+sa+liesse%2Cen+sa+folie%2Cen+sa+joie&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdans%20sa%20folie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdans%20sa%20joie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cen%20sa%20folie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cen%20sa%20joie%3B%2Cc0)* ; dans sa liesse, dans leur joie, dans leur bonheur,