# Preposition confusion: En va dans

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

Why do I use en here:
Mon frère habite en Françe

But here I use dans here:
Je suis dans le jardin

Comment: See: https://french.stackexchange.com/q/33924/4082 and https://french.stackexchange.com/q/13647/4082

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Dans** is used to express that you are *inside of something*

- Elle est dans la maison.
- L'oiseau est dans sa cage.
- Tu es dans la salle de bain.

**En** however defines a location which is more global such as a continent, a feminine region (country or whatsoever)

- Il habite en Russie. (la Russie -> feminine)
- Vous allez en Europe. (l'Europe -> feminine)
- Nous sommes allés en Californie (la Californie -> feminine)

But, you won't use *en* for masculine regions

- Vous êtes allés dans le Nord (le Nord -> masculine)
- Je vis aux États-Unis (les États-Unis -> masculine)
- Elle vit au Mexique (le Mexique -> masculine)
- Nous sommes aux Pays-Bas (les Pays-Bas -> masculine)

Obviously, these concern the very basic usage of both words, they are used in plenty more situations. For instance, you wouldn't say *Je suis dans la maison* for *I'm home*, but rather *Je suis à la maison*. This, is just a glimpse of the numerous other ways these words can be tricky to use.