# What's the difference in "en" and "dans"?

Tags: grammaire, en

Where do we use "en" and where do we use "dans"? What's the difference?

If I want to say that I work in finance or I work in IT. Would I use "en" or "dans"?

I recently started learning French, I am having difficulty understanding the difference between the two. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See [this](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13647/quelle-est-la-différence-entre-les-prépositions-dans-et-en-et-à) and [this](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33924/quelle-est-la-différence-entre-en-et-dans).